# What does the PowerShell phrase " | ? {...}" mean?

Tags: powershell

There are a couple of syntactic idiosyncrasies that PowerShell has that I can't find much documentation on. Today my question is the `? {...}`

example

```
PS> Get-SPServiceInstance | ? {$_.GetType.toString() -eq $varname}
```

I understand what the pipe means. I'm pretty sure `$_` is used to reference the current item in some kind of loop.

Can someone explain what this means? Also it would be great if someone could point me to a place where I can find out about PowerShell reserved symbols.

Comment: `man about_automatic_varables`, `man about_reserved_words`, `man about_operators`.

Comment: Here's some documentation: [SS64](https://ss64.com/ps/where-object.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
[^_^]16:46:21[1]>get-help ?

Name                              Category  Synopsis
----                              --------  --------
%                                 Alias     ForEach-Object
?                                 Alias     Where-Object
h                                 Alias     Get-History
r                                 Alias     Invoke-History
```

"?" is an alias for "where-object"

Comment: `gcm ?` is perhaps a little more direct, `get-command` being a more general way to determine what a command is (doesn't rely on help being present).

Comment: Thanks. I learned about some other aliases I didn't know about too.

Answer (score 4):

'?' is an alias to the `Where-Object` cmdlet. `Where-Object` takes a scriptblock (e.g '{...}') and evaluates its code. If the code evaluates to $true, the current object is written to the pipeline and is available to the next command in chain, otherwise ($false) the object is discarded.

For more help type:

```
Get-Help Where-Object -Full
```

Answer (score 1):

? is just an alias for where-object. You can get the list of all registered aliases using get-alias command.